# How to set up multi finger gesture control in 20.04

Tags: touchpad, 20.04, multi-touch, gestures

How can you setup Multi-finger (3 and 4 finger specially) gesture controls in Ubuntu 20.04? I am new and this is my 1st question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Fusuma. It worked for me. https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma