# Use gestures on touchpads --> Doesn't work

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I recently shifted from windows(Laptop HP-15da1058TU Intel core i5 8th Gen) to ubuntu 20.04 but I'm not able use my touchpad in similar fashion (specifically zoom in, zoom out and 3 finger screen movement gesture)

While this link says, I can https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/touchscreen-gestures.html.en

So, can anyone help me set it up. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you’re running (1) the brand/model of your computer (2) which gestures you’re not able to do. With this, it may be possible to offer a specific solution 

Comment: I notice that you added two of the three things that @matigo requested (the brand of your computer and the touch gestures you are attempting), but you didn't provide the *model*.  There are (really) hundreds of HP laptop models out there :-). Can you be more specific?  Not sure that it will lead to an answer, but the more detail you can provide, the better.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I've updated the details.

Comment: @matigo I've updated the details

Answer (score 0):

The gestures at the link you provide are for the 21.x version, if you are on 20.04 the gestures available are different. For example, there are no three-finger gestures are available, and gesture zooming in browsers specifically seem to be a whole other problem (https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/kdrmr0/pinch_to_zoom_and_ctrl_problem_while_browsing/).

When googling touch pad gestures 20.04 ubuntu there are many people having similar problems such as [How to set up multi finger gesture control in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243732/how-to-set-up-multi-finger-gesture-control-in-20-04)
and [Pinch zoom in browsers on Ubuntu 20.04 with Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261961/pinch-zoom-in-browsers-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-wayland) which both have solutions proposed that you could try.

Tutorials are also available to setup multi-touch gestures which you could try out:

https://omidioraemmanuel.medium.com/mac-like-touchpad-gestures-on-your-ubuntu-20-04-97bbb43e8e6c

https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/06/multi-touch-gestures-ubuntu-20-04/